# MS OneDrive Sharing

Tags: onedrive

I cannot seem to find the answer to this online so wondered if anyone would know.

I have set up a folder in OneDrive and shared it with two colleagues.  Does anyone know if, when I upload a new file to that folder, the colleagues will automatically get a notification to say that a new file has been uploaded to a folder that is shared with them?  Or do I have to email the colleagues myself telling them I have put something new in the folder?

I have worked out how to set up notifications on that folder when the colleague makes changes to files already in that folder.  Do I have to somehow do this the other way round for them to be notified?

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: These would be really easy to test yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When using OneDrive (OneDrive for personal), I think you need to tell your colleagues via sending email manually that a new file was added into the shared folder.
2. But when you have OneDrive for Business, you may create an alert to remind colleagues about the new uploaded files.

[image]

More detailed information, please check the similar thread,

[Alert on a OneDrive folder change](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/alert-on-a-onedrive-folder-change/8cfcf383-d7a6-4777-b695-6a3472a647a7)